# Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch heroku

Tags: java, heroku

I have a discord bot (it's not connected to a website ) and i wanted to host the runnable jar on heroku but as soon as i launch my bot this error always comes up
I'm not very fimiliar with Heroku so any help would be much appreciated